# ASP.Net MVC Routing issue for Home controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created one sample internet MVC application. Then created ProductsController with Index view.

Then in routing, I mapped product url with products/prodname/id with below routing rules.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProdDef",
                url: "{controller}/{name}/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But after this, contact page redirects me to home index controller action. ?? why so? Am I missing something and why other actions stopped working after creating only one rule for product.

Comment: If you need "ProdDef" to be used only when they access /Products, then specify that you only want that route: url: "Products/{name}/{id}/{action}". Otherwise, it is being used for every request since you are not specifying the controller or name and are making Id, and action optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your first route to something like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProdDef",
    url: "products/{name}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Otherwise that route will pretty much match anything. Remember that the order of your routes is important, as matching will be attempted in that order.

**Edit :**

The reason for this being that by default the routing handler makes no difference between `{controller}/{name}` and `{controller}/{action}`. They're the same format, only with different parameter names.

Here's a breakdown of what happens for say a given URL such as `/Home/Index`.

First route will be attempted first, has 4 parameters, 2 of which are optional so no values will be given if they're not present, leaving you with the following values :

- controller : Home
- name : Index
- action : null but will default to Index as specified
- id : null

As you can see both non-optional parameters are filled, therefore the route will match, but will not function as you might have expected. Same thing would happen no matter what the URL is, as long as it has a value for `controller` and `name`. Which brings me to my original answer, if you want that first route to match *only* incoming URLs for products, you need to add something that will allow the routing handler to differentiate it. By replacing `{controller}` with a hard-coded value of `products`, now that route will only match incoming URL's starting with products, leaving anything else to keep going down the route chain as expected.

Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: Thanks, Awaiting for some more explaination here for writing products/ in url in place of controller and ordering.